# How to Show popupViews

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uipopovercontroller

I have UiView,In my Uiview I have one Button And one textField.
When I click the button i need to show the popUp for date values.
when i click the textfield,other popUp with Names.If user select any name from there,that name will show in textfield.If User click on Button,Dates will be arranged by Ascending or Descending order.
Probelm is,My Uiview contain one Main table also.
Now how to differentiate that main table and popUp views.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your other popups as separate classes, and add them to your view when needed.

Example:

Create a class called "Names" which inherits from UIView or UIViewController
Create a class called "Dates" which inherits from UIView or UIViewController

To present any of those classes as a popup, you have 2 options:

- In case you used UIView, then you can present them with `[self addsubview:nview] & [UIView animationwithduration]` to make the popup animation.
- In case you used UIViewController, just use `[self presentViewController:nview]`.

Answer (score 0):

Each view will have tags, use them. 
`tableView.tag = 1;
 textBoxView.tag = 2;
 alertView.tag = 3;`

Now that you have the tags you can differentiate the views with respect to the tags.

Comment: I want to better Way than this.

Comment: @12345 then you could also try this [self.view subviews] will return the list of subviews then compare each view with isKindOf: class which will return true only if the condition is true.